# Why are the results not different when there's code in global?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, event-loop, setimmediate

Code Snippet-1

```
setTimeout(() => console.log("setTimeout1"));
setTimeout(() => console.log("setTimeout2"));
setImmediate(() => console.log("setImmediate1"));
setImmediate(() => console.log("setImmediate2"));
```

Code Snippet-2

```
setTimeout(() => console.log("setTimeout1"));
setTimeout(() => console.log("setTimeout2"));
setImmediate(() => console.log("setImmediate1"));
setImmediate(() => console.log("setImmediate2"));
console.log('hey');
```

Snippet 1's outputs, when run multiple times:

```
> setTimeout1, setTimeout2, setImmediate1, setImmediate2
> setImmediate1, setImmediate2, setTimeout1, setTimeout2
> setTimeout1, setImmediate1, setImmediate2, setTimeout2
```

Snippet 2 always returns in the following order:

```
> hey, setTimeout1, setTimeout2, setImmediate1, setImmediate2
```

I read about `setImmediate()` and `setTimeout()` and understood that the results might vary, but how does adding a `console.log()` in Snippet-2 return the same output every time?

Node: v16.18.0

Comment: You need to understand **async** call with javascript, your code is fine.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: FYI: asynchronous code/function is harder to work with because it'll execute in a different order every single time potentially which means that you have to make sure that your code will work no matter which path it takes whether it executes.

Comment: @TaherBensassi Then why is there no change when I run Snippet 2?

Comment: "*when run multiple times*" - how exactly do you run the snippet? Put the whole thing in a file, run it as a script? Or were you running it from a loop? Or from the REPL?

Comment: @TaherBensassi This has absolutely nothing to do with `async` functions

Comment: @Bergi I created a `test.js` file and manually ran it multiple times from the terminal using `node test.js`.